# OpenStack Compute-node communicate/ping vms run on it

Tags: openstack, monitor, ceilometer

In Ceilometer, when pollsters collect meter from VMs, it used hypervisor on compute-node. Now, I want to write new plugin for ceilometer and not use hypervisor to collect meter, I want to collect meter by a service that is installed on VMs (mean ceilometer get data from service), so I need compute-node must communicate with VMs by IP (private IP). Is there any solution to do this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

In general the internal network used by your Nova instances is kept intentionally separate from the compute hosts themselves as a security precaution (to ensure that someone logged into a Nova server isn't able to compromise your host).

For what you are proposing, it would be better to adopt a push model rather than a pull model: have a service running inside your instances that would publish data to some service accessible at a routeable ip address.